# Prolog: Append complex terms in a list

Tags: list, prolog, append, instantiation

I'm new with Prolog and I have a problem that I don't understand why.

I have a predicate (maybe wrong) that is to split a list in two lists. Something like that:

```
divide([],[],[]).

divide([PrimerEdificio|RestoEdificios], ListaA, ListaB) :- 
    divide(RestoEdificios, ListaParcialA, ListaParcialB),
    append([PrimerEdificio], ListaParcialA, ListaA),
    length(RestoEdificios, LongitudResto),
    length(ListaA, LongitudA),
    LongitudA > LongitudResto.

divide([PrimerEdificio|RestoEdificios], ListaA, ListaB) :- 
    length(RestoEdificios, LongitudResto),
    length(ListaA, LongitudA),
    LongitudA =< LongitudResto.
    append(RestoEdificios, [], ListaB).
```

When I try to append the terms into the list (case 2) the variable is not being instantiated but if I do directly in console it works fine. Here debug:

```
[trace] 1 ?- divide([ed(3,5,6), ed(4,5,6), ed(5,6,7)], X, Y).
    Call: (7) divide([ed(3, 5, 6), ed(4, 5, 6), ed(5, 6, 7)], _G3026, _G3027) ? creep
    Call: (8) divide([ed(4, 5, 6), ed(5, 6, 7)], _G3140, _G3141) ? creep
    Call: (9) divide([ed(5, 6, 7)], _G3140, _G3141) ? creep
    Call: (10) divide([], _G3140, _G3141) ? creep
    Exit: (10) divide([], [], []) ? creep
    Call: (10) append([ed(5, 6, 7)], [], _G3144) ? creep
    Exit: (10) append([ed(5, 6, 7)], [], _G3144) ? creep
```

I would hope that **_G3144** (last sentence) is instantiated to [ed(5, 6, 7)].

Any help?

Comment: `append(RestoEdificios, [], ListaB)` is the same as `RestoEdificios = ListaB` (you're appending an empty list, which does nothing to the list). Not sure why your `creep` is showing `_G3144` in that last case. Seeing the very next trace line might help. Also note that `append([PrimerEdificio], ListaParcialA, ListaA)` is the same as `ListaA = [PrimerEdificio|ListaPacialA]`. You don't need `append/3` for these two situations.

Comment: Using the code shown, there are singleton variable warnings, meaning there are variables only used once within a predicate clause. You need to check those to make sure they are intentional and fix them if not. Also, you have a period after `LongitudA =< LongitudResto.` which generates an error. Is the code you show here really the code you ran? I'm starting to suspect it's not. I tried your code and did not see the same trace.